# Fetch file in previous folder in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have the following folder structure:

```
-> BrowserExtensions
   -> Chrome
      - background.js
      - manifest.json
      - script.js
   -> Firefox
      - file.txt
   - data.xml
```

The arrows indicate the folders.

In my `background.js` I want to fetch the file `data.xml`. Unfortunately it does not work. I can only access files in the `Chrome` folder.

I'm using this function:

```
function LoadData() {
    fetch('../data.xml').then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Do I need specific permissions in my `manifest.json`? Or is it blocked due to security reasons?

Comment: Just curious: Are there any error messages in the console? "Or is it blocked due to security reasons?" You're trying to access a file outside your extension directory. If you could do that, that would be a security problem. And how would it work in a packed extension?

Comment: It gives me the error message `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`. The extension is only meant to be used in combination with a desktop app which determines the file's locations. The `data.xml` is created by the desktop app and then accessed by the extension in the `Chrome` folder (and later an extension in the `Firefox` folder). To save resources I wanted to create this file only once but I could of course generate it directly in the `Chrome` and `Firefox `folder. But I thought there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: The root of the extension is where manifest.json is. You can't go beyond the root because it's the root. Put the file inside the extension.